# Marshal C# class with reference members to C++

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, marshalling

We have a task to pass a class with a reference to another class from C# to C++. C# class looks like this:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public class ImageInfo
{
    public uint Width;
    public uint Height;
    public uint Stride;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
internal class FrameInfo
{
    public int FrameNumber;
    public double TimeStamp;
    public ImageInfo Image; // This is the problem
}
```

C++ struct looks like this (pack is also 1):

```cpp
struct FrameInfo
{
public:

    unsigned int    frameNumber;
    double          timeStamp;
    ImageInfo       *image;
};

struct ImageInfo
{
public:

    unsigned int     m_width;
    unsigned int     m_height;
    unsigned int     m_stride;
};
```

We pass the C# class to C++ in such a way:

```cs
[DllImport("ourLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int OnFrame(int pId, FrameInfo pFrame);
```

And accept it in C++:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int OnFrame(int pId, const FrameInfo *pFrame);
```

As a result in the `FrameInfo` struct we have not a reference but an embedded class. Memory layout looks like this:

```
0..3 bytes:   uint   frameNumber

4..11 bytes:  double timeStamp

12..15 bytes: uint   width

16..19 bytes: uint height

etc...
```

instead of:

```
0..3 bytes:   uint   frameNumber

4..11 bytes:  double timeStamp

12..15 bytes: ImageInfo* image  // pointer to the image
```

Class embedding causes an additional data copying that makes us very upset. We tried to pass the reference as `IntPtr` with the help of `Marshal.StructureToPtr()` but MSDN says that

> "StructureToPtr copies the contents of structure to the pre-allocated block of memory"

so that it also copies the data.

Then we tried to use C-style pointers in C#:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
internal unsafe class FrameInfo
{
    public int FrameNumber;
    public double TimeStamp;
    public ImageInfo *Image;
}
```

Compiler says that "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type"

OK. Then we tried a strange not-documented function `__makeref()` and then casting it to the IntPtr but it also has rather strange memory layout.

So, is there any way to pass the reference just as usual reference?

Comment: Have you tried deriving `ImageInfo` from `MarshalByRefObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pack` is probably wrong. Visual C++ doesn't `Pack=1`, it normally `Pack=0`...

Now... You could cheat a little:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal class FrameInfo
{
    public int FrameNumber;
    public double TimeStamp;
    public IntPtr Image; // This is the problem
    public uint Width;
    public uint Height;
    public uint Stride;
}

[DllImport("NativeLibrary", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int OnFrame(int pId, FrameInfo fi);
```

and then

```
var fi = new FrameInfo { FrameNumber = 1, TimeStamp = 2, Width = 3, Height = 4, Stride = 5 };

var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(fi, GCHandleType.Pinned);

try
{
    fi.Image = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject() + 2 * sizeof(double) + IntPtr.Size;

    OnFrame(1, fi);
}
finally
{
    handle.Free();
}
```

Note how I've "merged" the two `class` together... The `IntPtr` now points "inside" the `class`.

Note that the `IntPtr Image` will be "correct" only until the `handle.Free()`

But at this point, I would incapsulate everything in another method, like:

```
[DllImport("NativeLibrary", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int OnFrame(int pId, IntPtr fi);

public static int OnFrameSharp(int pId, FrameInfo fi)
{
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(fi, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    try
    {
        IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        fi.Image = ptr + 2 * sizeof(double) + IntPtr.Size;

        return OnFrame(pId, ptr);
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

In this way I would gain something in speed, because I pin the `FrameInfo` and the CLR doesn't have to re-pin it.

Comment: Yeah, that works great! Though I believe that `2 * sizeof(double)` should be `sizeof(int) + sizeof(double)`

Comment: @AntonEgorov No, `double` are normally aligned on 8 byte boundary, so they need some padding before them if they are preceded by a `int`

Answer (score 2):

> So, is there any way to pass the reference just as usual reference?

No, references are not stable due to the garbage collector, an object has to be pinned first.  The pinvoke marshaller refuses to do so for non-trivial object graphs.  You'd have to declare the FrameInfo.Image member as IntPtr and use GC.Alloc + AddrOfPinnedObject

You can get *somewhere* in this case, ImageInfo ought to be a struct type.  Which allows you declare a pointer:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ImageInfo {
    public uint Width;
    public uint Height;
    public uint Stride;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal unsafe class FrameInfo {
    public int FrameNumber;
    public double TimeStamp;        
    public ImageInfo* Image;
}
```

And you can easily initialize FrameInfo.Image as long as the struct is stored on the stack (local variable or method argument):

```
var info = new ImageInfo { Width = 5, Height = 6, Stride = 7 };
var frame = new FrameInfo { FrameNumber = 1, TimeStamp = 2, Image = &info };
OnFrame(42, frame);
```